# Dhtmlx ad TreeView Grid - How to convert this json object

Tags: json, dhtmlx

I have a json object that looks like the below.  Its nested object where the first level is date, second is hour third level is country.  I would like a tree where one can drill into date->hour->country.  How to a transform the below so can use the treegrid control?

```
{u'2012-10-31': {'0': {u'SG': {'data': ['5020', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '1': {u'SG': {'data': ['5256', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '10': {u'SG': {'data': ['7836', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '11': {u'SG': {'data': ['7440', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '12': {u'SG': {'data': ['7949', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '13': {u'SG': {'data': ['8781', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '14': {u'SG': {'data': ['10739', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '15': {u'SG': {'data': ['13083', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '16': {u'SG': {'data': ['15182', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '17': {u'SG': {'data': ['16339', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '18': {u'SG': {'data': ['16169', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '19': {u'SG': {'data': ['12565', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '2': {u'SG': {'data': ['5748', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '20': {u'SG': {'data': ['9801', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '21': {u'SG': {'data': ['9266', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '22': {u'SG': {'data': ['10526', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '23': {u'SG': {'data': ['9570', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '3': {u'SG': {'data': ['6755', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '4': {u'SG': {'data': ['7099', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '5': {u'SG': {'data': ['7013', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '6': {u'SG': {'data': ['7498', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '7': {u'SG': {'data': ['6705', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '8': {u'SG': {'data': ['7770', '0', '0', '0', '0']}},
                 '9': {u'SG': {'data': ['7976', '0', '0', '0', '0']}}}}
```

Comment: I actually have the paid version of dhtmlx with support.  There support is terrible.  Big mistake to pay for dhtmlx.

Answer (score 0):

Please use to change the format of JSON as given below the example.

```
{"rows":[{"id":date,"data":[{"value":"1212","image":"folder.gif"},"12",2012,15000,"=sum","","",214,0,0,0,""],
                    "rows":[{"id":hour,"data":[{"value":"121","image":"folder.gif"},"12",2012,5000,"=sum","","",215,0,0,0,""],
                        "rows":[{"id":country,"data":[{"value":"1212"},null,2012,2000,"=c3","","",215,0,0,0,""]}]}]}]}
```